# Capybara (poltergeist) cannot find checkbox in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, capybara, poltergeist

I cannot get Capybara for find a checkbox element.

I've tried all the usual ways:

```
find_field
check
find
click_on
```

It's as if the element isn't there. If I select the parent element, and look at it's innerHTML the checkbox is included:

```
(byebug) all(:css, '.checkbox.form-group').last['innerHTML']
\n    <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"google_agreed_to_terms_at\" value=\"1\" required=\"true\" ng-model=\"agreed_to_terms\" required-notification=\"Please agree to the terms and conditions\" class=\"ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required\" bs-validation=\"\">\
```

but selecting the child elements it's not there:

```
(byebug) all(:css, '.checkbox.form-group').last.all :xpath, './*'
[#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="label" 
path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/FORM[1]/DIV[1]/LABEL[1]">]
```

I feel like I'm going mad.

Here's the relevant code (copied from `save_and_open_page`)

```
<div class="checkbox form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" id="agreed_to_terms_at" value="1" required="true" ng-model="agreed_to_terms" required-notification="Please agree to the terms and conditions" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" bs-validation="">
  <label class="label-light" for="agreed_to_terms_at">
     I have read and agree to the terms</label>
</div>
```

I thought maybe rails was generating slightly non-compliant HTML, so I've gone to writing the checkbox by hand, but it didn't help.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkbox is hidden to allow for uniform styling across all browsers. Since you have a label element correctly associated you can tell check to click the label instead of the actual checkbox

```
check('agreed_to_terms_at', allow_label_click: true)
```

which will click the checkbox if visible and if not it will click the label. If you want it to only click the label you can do

```
find(:label, 'I have read and agree').click
```

Or

```
find(:label, for:'agreed_to_terms_at').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to CSS styling, the checkbox element was being hidden and the label used to present it. So the element was getting skipped over by capybara's default behaviour to ignore hidden elements.

I worked around it using

```
find('#agreed_to_terms_at', :visible => false).trigger('click')
```

Comment: can't you just add in your spec_helper: `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` ? (to avoid using your solution EVERY time you need it)

Comment: I have considered doing it, as it's not the first time I've found it a hassle, but I do understand the value of capybara requiring you to say "yes, I know the user can't see this but I want to change it anyway", to avoid use cases where hidden elements are manipulated accidentally by the spec providing a false pass.

Comment: Using trigger('click') or setting Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements to false should be solutions of last resort when testing an app (fine if scraping a site) because they perform actions a user never could